# I have 2 dropdowns, i want to search for data in the database that matches both attributes. My code below doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql

There are 3 pages and one dropdown is working, but I can't make both of the filter the data. It's probably a syntax error as I'm a beginner at PHP. I did try to change search.php in many ways but it doesn't seem to help. Any help is appreciated.

```
Products.html

<form action="search.php" method='post'>
     <select name="PC">

<option value="HP PC"> HP PC</option>
<option value="Samsung Laptop">Samsung Laptop</option>
<option value="Sony Phone">Sony phone</option>
<option value="Dell PC">Dell PC</option>
</select>
        <select price="price">

<option value="599.00"> 599</option>
<option value="300.00"> 300</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id= "searchBtn" name='name' price='price' value= "Go!"/>
           </form>

 Search.php
 <?php
include "main.php";

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name=$_POST['PC'];
search($name);
}
if(isset($_POST['price'])){
$price=$_POST['price'];
search($price);}
?>
Main.php

function search($name,$price){
//Connect to the database
$conn = connect();

  $query = "SELECT * FROM t_product WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND price LIKE '%$price%' ";

   $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results) ){
    echo "<tr>
        <td>$row[name]</td>
        <td>$row[price]</td>
        <td><img src='$row[imagepath]' width='150' height='100' /></td>
        </form>

        </td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

//close the table tags
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: First, you have to call your `price` function with 2 arguments (`$name,$price`) and not with only one of them. Second: How will your select the products with a price match `price LIKE '%$price%'`? the `LIKE %..%` is for string operations a not not numeric values. I'm not sure how you want to search for a price, please explain it more.

Comment: what do you mean by the first line?

Comment: I get the second point though.

Comment: your function `search($name,$price)` expects 2 arguments and you only call it with one, if you only want to search for a name OR a price and not both you need to edit your search function or just call it with both values.

Comment: i want to search for an object in the db given both the name and the price

Comment: I can give you the advise to test the query first with some data base management tool (PHPMyAdmin maybe I don't know what you have at hand), and if that works with some test data implement it in PHP yourself. Most development tools also have a good data base integration to test queries, if you develop PHP with a good tool it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah, I am not as bad at SQL as I am at PHP. I will need so much php help and probably AJAX, I want the result to appear on the same page. That would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**products.html**

```
<form action="search.php" method='post'>
    <select name="PC">
        <option value="HP PC"> HP PC</option>
        <option value="Samsung Laptop">Samsung Laptop</option>
        <option value="Sony Phone">Sony phone</option>
        <option value="Dell PC">Dell PC</option>
     </select>
     <select name="price">
         <option value="599.00"> 599</option>
         <option value="300.00"> 300</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" id= "searchBtn" name='name' price='price' value= "Go!"/>
</form>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php

if(isset( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) ) {

    $name=$_POST[ 'PC' ];

}

if(isset( $_POST[ 'price' ] ) ) {

    $price=$_POST[ 'price' ];

}

$conn = connect();

$query = "SELECT * FROM t_product WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND price LIKE '%$price%' ";

$results = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

echo '<table>';

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $results ) ) {

    echo "<tr>
        <td>" .$row[name]. "</td>
        <td>" .$row[price]. "</td>
        <td><img src='".$row[imagepath]."' width='150' height='100' /></td>
        </tr>";
}
echo '</table>';


?>
```

Try this.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\TZON\search.php on line 11

Comment: I just noticed you also have an error in your HTML `<select price="price">` it should be `<select name="price">` obviously. :)

Comment: THANKKKK YOUUUUU. That was the main problem. <select name="price">

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_product WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' AND price LIKE '%$price%' ";
```

This is most likely why your query doesn't work. Try taking the %$name% and %$price% directly as $name and $price.

Anyway, to see the errors for the MySql query, try this:

echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));

Then, you'll see exactly what the error is and you can fix the query

But first, try

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_product WHERE name LIKE $name AND price LIKE $price ";
```

Make sure to define your variables accordingly.

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for search(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\TZON\search.php on line 6 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\TZON\main.php on line 106

Notice: Undefined variable: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\TZON\main.php on line 110

Comment: I told you to define the variables, like this: $name = blabla and $price = bla bla. Have you done that? Also, check you have the variables defined and accessible across all files.